# SSL error navigation blocked

Tags: validation, security, ssl, https

Hi I have recently activated SSL on my domain however Safari, Edge and firefox are saying my site is insecure edge is showing this message:

The hostname in the website’s security certificate differs from the website you are trying to visit.

```
Error Code: DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID
```

However chrome seems to have no issues displaying the site

I have looked up my SSL certificate and it says this (MyDomain.co.uk I have changed from my real domain):

> Certificate does not match name MyDomain.co.uk
>
> Subject   hostinger.com Valid from 20/Jun/2017 to 13/Mar/2018
>   Issuer    COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
>
> Subject   COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA Valid from
>   12/Feb/2014 to 11/Feb/2029 Issuer COMODO RSA Certification Authority
>
> Subject   COMODO RSA Certification Authority Valid from 30/May/2000 to
>   30/May/2020 Issuer    AddTrust External CA Root

Could this be the problem? 
And how do I resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you need to get a certificate for the specific domain you're using it on.

Comment: I assume my hosting provider can fix this as they issued the certificate ?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like an issue for customer support

Comment: They're on it, thanks